# Azure Cosmos Master Token Expiration

Tags: token, azure-cosmosdb

Fairly new `Azure Cosmos Db`. Starting to implement some direct http calls to the `Cosmos`.

I have successfully created a `Master Token` and used it inside my `Postman` environment. I can access data. The trouble is that eventually this `Master Token` times out, and I guess that confuses me.

Does a `Master Token` have a limited life? I was hoping to be able to create 1x token for my service and be done with it, but I'm starting to think I'll need to setup the `Resource Token` middleware somewhere.

Can anyone shed light on how I'm expected to use a `Master Token`, the name throws me off because it sounds like Master should last forever (to me) yet it is only good for 15 minutes. Is a `Master Token` simply just used to run testing?

I've been using this site as my resource: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/access-control-on-cosmosdb-resources?redirectedfrom=MSDN#constructkeytoken

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Master tokens provide admin access to the Cosmos account and do not expire. Resource tokens provide access to the data within the account. These do expire and have max lifetime of 5 hours. You need the master token to create a resource token. You can learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/secure-access-to-data).

Generally speaking the experience of using one of the SDK's for Cosmos DB will provide you with a better experience as it does a bunch of work for you, including managing the resource tokens. If using the .NET or Java SDK's you'll also get faster performance as these both talk directly to the physical partitions rather than going through the services' gateway.

Comment: I'm attempting to embed my logic in a server side app (http call), was hoping to just put a master key there and zip it up tightly. I'll need a Resource Token for my Authorization header for this call, guess Ill host another service in Azure functions to generate my tokens? All users will share the same token service / user, but I'll be generating them about 5x/second.

Comment: 5 resource tokens a second? I should point out that our control plane has no latency SLA so you may or may not get 5 a second from the service. You should stress test this. There are some fairly large customers who use resource tokens so this may be fine. Just want to point it out.

Comment: Thank you for that heads up!  Could I store my token as a singleton for the hour? All users can share the resource token and will just refresh when needed, users do not have any way to authenticate.

Comment: @markokstate - please consider asking a new question, rather than posting additional questions in comments. Or take the discussion to [chat]. Best to avoid additional Q&A, and discussion, in comments.