# Where to configure azure cosmos database resource token validity period for documentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

It is said that master token can last up to 5 hours, but defaults to 1. How to configure this in the Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.core library.

Comment: Could you plz help me to know if this issue is regarding resource token or master token because these are two distinct tokens use for different purpose?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700354/azure-cosmos-master-token-expiration, if it clarifies your issue.